# Regex to accept space only if accompanied by an alphanumeric or hyphen/underscore?

Tags: regex

Current regex: `^[\w\- ]+$`

Problem being this is also accepting strings as  " " which is unacceptable.
e.g. Acceptable
"SO", "43_das", "e2da", "_", "543543" and also should not accept if there is a space in the end of string like "ab12 "

Comment: Maybe `^\w+(?:[- ]\w+)*$`. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Your SO post is the one with the least effort I've seen in a while man...

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat what can I do, that is all there is to it :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hey thanks for the feedback, however this doesn't accept strings like "ab12 " with a space in the end!

Comment: Oh yes. And I guess the next pattern I can share will not work either because you are going to add more and more sample inputs. Do that **once**. Add *all* the ***requirements*** to the question itself. Just samples won't do.

Comment: Ah, forget about it, anubhava will give you all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[\w-]+(?: +[\w-]+)*$/
```

To allow spaces only between non-space characters.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oJ1hM2/1)

Comment: Last space `"abcd "` is not really accompanied by word char or hyphen. Please clarify the requirements in question.

Comment: If space isn't allowed in the end then my regex in answer will work isn't it?

Comment: Once again that minor difference is only due to not-so-clear requirements in question. You should've clarified is hyphen or underscore is allowed at start/end or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
^([\w\-] )+$
```